# Sorting this Map<String, FullName> in Java

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have a Map where FullName is an object and contains another object of class Name that contains FirstName and LastName. Firstname and last names are String. (Yes i know its a bad design, but i am trying to learn sorting)

The key String is just id's such as 1,2,3,...

I want to sort based on the full name(both firstname and last name), and just return a list of id's.

This is the code i have so far, but i am getting a syntax error on the sorted portion where i am passing the comparator. And also I am pretty sure i am doing something incorrect semantically too.

```
List<String> listofIds = map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(new ValueComparator(map))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(toList());

class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    Map<String, FullName> base;

    public ValueComparator(Map<String, FullName> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        FullName fullName1 = base.get(a);
        FullName fullName2 = base.get(b);
        return(fullName1.getName().getFirstName()
               .compareTo(fullName2.getName().getFirstName()));
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to compare Map entries together. So what you need is a Comparator<Map.Entry<String, FullName>>, not a Comparator<String>.

Comment: It would be helpful to have the code for FullName since it's used in the code you do share, and actual error. For more advice on how to write a good question, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparator is for `String` objects, but `map.entrySet().stream()` returns a stream of `Entry<String, FullName>` objects.

As suggested by JB in the comments, you can use the static `Comparator` method `#comparing` to quickly build a `Comparator`:

```
List<String> listofIds = map.entrySet().stream().sorted(
  Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getValue().getName().getFirstName())
).map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(toList());
```

You can take advantage of `Comparator` being a functional interface like this:

```
List<String> listofIds = map.entrySet().stream().sorted(
    (e1, e2) -> e1.getValue().getName().getFirstName().compareTo(
       e2.getValue().getName().getFirstName())
).map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(toList());
```

If you still want to use a `Comparator` object, you could use:

```
private static class ValueComparator implements Comparator<Entry<String, FullName>> {

  @Override
  public int compare(Entry<String, FullName> e1, Entry<String, FullName>> e2) {
    FullName fullName1 = e1.getValue();
    FullName fullName2 = e2.getValue();
    return fullName1.getName().getFirstName()
           .compareTo(fullName2.getName().getFirstName());
  }
}
```

Comment: An even better solution would be to use `Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getValue().getName().getFirstName())`

Comment: @JBNizet I wasn't aware of that function, nice!

Comment: I'm sure you can make the adjustment to compare both :) Maybe give it a try and if you run into trouble you can ask a new question. Glad I can help!